# How to read and combine Excel files quickly

Tags: r

I have these excel sheets with hundreds/thousands of rows and I need to read them and get specific values to plot.

my code looks like this

```
h2ax.read <- function(file){
  require(xlsx)
  lfile = list.files( pattern = file)
  ldata = lapply(lfile, read.xlsx, sheetIndex = 1)
  combined1 = do.call("rbind", ldata)
}
```

It takes rather long even for 2 excel files of 1000 rows each

```
system.time(h2ax.read("1nmE2"))
   user  system elapsed 
118.976   0.801 141.135
```

what should I do improve the time, because I need to call this function from another function to read many such excel files at one. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try the `readxl` package instead.

Comment: I'd suggest trying the `readxl` package, which depends on `Rcpp` rather than `rJava`. Can't say in advance if it's faster but I'd guess it is.

Comment: Thank you both. `readxl` does excellent job. With that I get `system.time(h2ax.read("1nmE2"))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.058   0.003   0.061 
There were 32 warnings (use warnings() to see them)` Btw, I checked the output is same as my code with `read.xlsx`. Should I ignore the warnings? Thanks MrFlick for making the subject line more sensible.

Comment: I guess I can ask another question about `read_excel` here. It does not read the next column after a blank column. Can you get me how to get around that?